# how to test if the target variables is correlated with protected variables?

Tags: bias

I wonder how to check if the protected variables in fairness either encoded in the other features (non-protected). Or if they are not sufficiently correlated with target variables so adding them does not  improve performance in predication(classification)?. If there is a Python tutorial showing that , it will be useful.

Regards,